# Oracle: Create context index during runtime

Tags: indexing, oracle11g

What happens, if i create a context index on a table containing a lot of data during runtime?
Is it advisable to take the application down as the table will be locked or doesn't this have an impact?

Comment: You can create it. No application should be stopped (assume that the application does not hold a lock on a table). During index creation DML are not possible.

Comment: what is the point to create index in runtime? are u using dynamic SQL? the execution time of creating index is depending on the volume of the data, if u have only a few million rows or a few ten millions, then it's not a problem, but above that it could be taking so long